# JS Рекурсия с помощью reduce()

Tags: javascript

Есть массив объектов

```js
let data =     [
    {
        id: 10,
        name: 'text1',
        children: [
            {
                id: 101,
                name: 'text2',
                children: [
                    {
                        id: 1001,
                        name: 'text3',
                        children: []
                    },
                    {
                        id: 1002,
                        name: 'text4',
                        children: [{
                            id: 10003,
                            name: 'text5',
                            children: [{
                                id: 100004,
                                name: 'text4',
                                children: []
                            }]
                        }]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: 102,
                name: 'text4',
                children: []
            }

        ]
    },
    {
        id: 11,
        name: 'text1',
        children: [{
            id: 111,
            name: 'text2',
            children: [{
                id: 1111,
                name: 'text4',
                children: []
            }]
        }]
    }
]



function searchItems(valueBySearch, items){

    return items.reduce(function f(acc, curr, index) {
        return (curr.name.toUpperCase().includes(valueBySearch.toUpperCase())) ? acc.concat(curr) :
            (curr.children && curr.children.length) ? curr.children.reduce(f, acc) : acc;
    }, []);

}

console.log(searchItems('text4', data))
```

Мне нужно найти все совпадающие с условием объекты, я могу это сделать с помощью цикла forEach рекурсивно вызывая функцию если чилдрен больше нуля, но хочу попробовать это сделать с помощью reduce() если это возможно. Сейчас, почему-то возвращаются не все объекты

Comment: на каждой итерации ты возвращаешь только один объект, если тебе нужна коллекция - то и возвращать ты должен коллекцию

Comment: Не совсем понимаю как это сделать

Comment: накапливай в аккумуляторе, а не просто возвращай один объект.

Comment: upd, но не возвращается объект с  id 100004. Вот мой результат [
  { id: 1002, name: 'text4', children: [ [Object] ] },
  { id: 102, name: 'text4', children: [] },
  { id: 1111, name: 'text4', children: [] }
]

Comment: возможно потому что return прерывает дальшее хождение в глубь

Comment: вы недавно эту рекурсивную структуру формировали из обычного массива. не хотите поиски свои совершить на обычном массиве перед преобразованием?

Comment: мне пришлось совсем отказаться от плоской структуры, и получаю эти данные теперь уже только в дереве. Думаете ради функции поиска стоит все каждый раз переводить  в плоскую структуру, и там искать? Я, правда, не знаю как лучше, есть ли легкие способы дерево сделать плоским?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Рекурсивный вызов внутри `reduce`

```js
let data =     [
    {
        id: 10,
        name: 'text1',
        children: [
            {
                id: 101,
                name: 'text2',
                children: [
                    {
                        id: 1001,
                        name: 'text3',
                        children: []
                    },
                    {
                        id: 1002,
                        name: 'text4',
                        children: [{
                            id: 10003,
                            name: 'text5',
                            children: [{
                                id: 100004,
                                name: 'text4',
                                children: []
                            }]
                        }]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: 102,
                name: 'text4',
                children: []
            }

        ]
    },
    {
        id: 11,
        name: 'text1',
        children: [{
            id: 111,
            name: 'text2',
            children: [{
                id: 1111,
                name: 'text4',
                children: []
            }]
        }]
    }
]


function searchItems(valueBySearch, items) {
    valueBySearch = valueBySearch.toUpperCase();

    return items.reduce((acc, curr) => {

        if (curr.name.toUpperCase() === valueBySearch) {
            acc.push(curr);
        }

        if (curr.children && curr.children.length > 0) {
            acc = acc.concat(searchItems(valueBySearch, curr.children));
        }

        return acc;

    }, []);
}

console.log(searchItems('text4', data))
```